# I can't load savegame slots on Candy Box 2

Tags: candy-box-2

I try to load http://candybox2.net/?slot=1  but the browser can't load the page...

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Did you turn on autosave in the first place?

Comment: I am having the same problem on Google Chrome. My auto save was on and I have manually saved like 20 times at least.

Comment: I tested this out on Chrome and had the same problem. I hit refresh a few times and eventually it worked.

Comment: My guess is that since the game just came out the server might be getting overloaded.

Comment: @Batophobia Your game is saved on your local computer actually, in browser cache.

Comment: @3ventic Yes but you still connect to the server to get the web page.

Comment: @Batophobia but you can also save the page and play it without internet connection

Comment: I'm having this same issue and the presence or lack of 'www' at the start has no impact. Very disappointing since I had just recently "finished" the story of the game. I am also on chrome, and I can see my save (in slot one of the dropdown) on the "new" game I started when I visited the site, but no way to load it that I can find.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. I think it has to do with the way the site stores data locally. If you visited *www.candybox2.net* to play the game initially you cannot use the default load links to load the game. As far as your browser is concerned they are not the same site. You need to load http://www.candybox2.net/?slot=1 instead.

So, if you visited **www.candybox2.net** your slots are:

[www.candybox2.net/?slot=1](http://www.candybox2.net/?slot=1)
[www.candybox2.net/?slot=2](http://www.candybox2.net/?slot=2)
[www.candybox2.net/?slot=3](http://www.candybox2.net/?slot=3)
[www.candybox2.net/?slot=4](http://www.candybox2.net/?slot=4)
[www.candybox2.net/?slot=5](http://www.candybox2.net/?slot=5)

If you visited **candybox2.net** your slots are:

http://candybox2.net/?slot=1
http://candybox2.net/?slot=2
http://candybox2.net/?slot=3
http://candybox2.net/?slot=4
http://candybox2.net/?slot=5

Comment: The links are fine as such. :)

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is that you cleared your browser cache and the save was lost as a direct result. The game mentions a few things that will cause you to lose your save on its save page:

> Choose text save if :
>    - You want to continue playing on another device or browser
>    - You want to share your save with someone else
>    - For some reason you want to empty your browser cache
>     (which will erase your local saves)

To keep your save you need to use the same browser (not in private/incognito), same device and not clear your browser cache. If you are changing browser or device, or clearing your cache, get the text save from the save page so you can later restore your save.